# Is there a JQuery Table plugin that supports an HTML table as an AJAX datasource

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I've been evaluating a number of JQuery table plugins to handle my paging and sorting needs. I am looking for something that allows be to page and sort my tables with an AJAX call.

The problem that I am having is that all the plugins that I have found expect the Ajax call to return JSON. This is perfect for simple scenarios but falls down when I want to apply complex formatting to my tables, as soon as I want my table to include links or icons or other complex rendering I am faced with reproducing server side code that generates these links or chooses the appropriate icon as client side code to do the same thing.

What I would like to do is return the new table data as an html table and have the plugin replace the existing table with the returned table (either directly or by copying cells, the specifics are not important). Are there any reccomendations for the best way to do this?

Comment: how would the plugin know how many rows you have in order to page unless it is specified in a json/xml result object?

Comment: I know its not jquery, but YUI provides EXACTLy waht your looking for.  Use their datatable with a formatter and your all set.  I have used their tables to put inline autocomplete editing in.

Comment: This could be passed as a parameter. Any solution that uses AJAX for paging will run into this problem. Regardless of whether the data comes back as JSON, CSV, HTML or any other format.

Comment: Your hesitancy to use JSON as a data format seems to ignore the meta-data that's necessary in a datagrid. You want to get back the number of rows returned, and how many might be returned when there's pagination. A structured data format gives you a way to do that, while plain HTML does not. Additionally, JSON can be much more compact than rather verbose HTML. I think JSON adds responsiveness. You're also ignoring the fact that for example YUI and DataTables allow for formatter functions to transform your data the same way your html would be. Best of luck.

Comment: I do understand this artlung but the problem that I am trying to solve (and to be honest have yet to find a ready solution solution to) is that formatting my data using javascript is a pretty major violation of DRY. In an application where formatting consistency is essential it does not seem to be prudent to write formatting logic in javascript to mirror my server side code.

Comment: Hmmm. You may want to reconsider your approach. Usually, a technique becomes standard because it is a best practice. Pre-creating an HTML table, sending it via AJAX, and replacing an existing is possible--even easy! However, it is grossly inefficient. I suggest you take another look at simply rendering the data server side, formatting it as a JsonResult, and sticking it into a table client side. These uses the least bandwidth, provides the most flexibility, and is consistent with best practices. Using JSON is not that hard. MVC has built in methods to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best option will be to create a controller action that returns a partial view which contains your table. The partial view can contain any JavaScript based table/grid you want. This solution has no dependency at all on any specific grid/table implementation.

For instance, let's say you have a strongly typed partial view of type **ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<Foo>>** named FooList.ascx

You would then define some action in your controller that rendered this partial

```
// For paging support, you would probably need to modify this action to accept
// a parameter that could be used to tell which records to retrieve.
// This would also require the appropriate route. However, this is beyond
// the scope of this example.
public PartialViewResult List()
{
  // get the collection of stuff that you want to display
  var items = this.itemRepository.GetItems();

  // return the partial
  return PartialView("FooList", items);
}
```

In your view where this partial is going to be used, you will want to have something like the following...

```
<!-- this <div> will contain the partial, which we will be able to update via AJAX -->
<div id="FooList">
    <%-- this assumes a collection of "items" is available in Model.Items --%>
    <% Html.RenderPartial("FooList", Model.Items); %>
</div>

<!-- use an AJAX ActionLink to update the table -->
<%=
    Ajax.ActionLink
    (
        "Click Me to Update the Table using AJAX!",
        "List",
        new AjaxOptions()
        {
            HttpMethod = "GET",
            LoadingElementId = "FooList"
        }
    )
%>
```

All we're doing here is using the [ASP.NET MVC AJAX Helper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajaxhelper_members.aspx) to create a link that will generate an AJAX GET request to the List action in your controller. Also, by defining the **LoadingElementId** property in the AjaxOptions object, we have told the helper that we want to replace the inner contents of **<div id="FooList">** with the results of the AJAX request.

When a user clicks that link, an AJAX request will cause your List action to be invoked. Your list action simply returns the rendered contents of the partial view FooList.ascx. The existing contents of the div with id="FooList" will be replaced by the contents that were retrieved from the AJAX request. In the above example, the controller action will always select the same data, which is not really what you want. In a real scenario, you would have to modify the controller action to retrieve the appropriate data for your partial view. I couldn't suggest an effective way for you to handle that without knowing the details for your implementation.

If you don't want to use a link, then just look at the HTML and JavaScript that is generated by the Ajax.ActionLink helper and adapt it to your own needs. For instance, build your own custom helper, or just manually write out the JavaScript.

Lastly, don't forget to include the MVC AJAX JavaScript source files. I recommend including them in your master page. For example:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

have a look at http://www.datatables.net/ i think this will fill your needs :)

Very good it is too!

as for the formatting thru JSON i am doing this quite hapily... just make sure you encode any funny characters and it should be fine.

Comment: Do you have an example for using an html table as the ajax datasource rather than JSON? I looked at datatables extensively and it didnt seem to be able to do this.

Comment: DataTables is a JSON solution, which the OP is not interested in. http://www.datatables.net/usage/server-side JSON all the way

Comment: FYI, the default usage is just to generate an HTML table then datatables does the rest - no JSON....

However to make it more efficient for paging/very parge tables serverside processing is recomended.

Comment: By default datatables uses the tables generated in HTML see the sourcecode behind the basic example - http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_config.html

Comment: I don't think you are understanding the question properly. I want the datatables AJAX functionality but I want my AJAX response to be an HTML table rather than a JSON array. This allows me to use the same code for my initial rendering as for my AJAX responses. And prevents me rewriting my server side formatting code as client side code.

Comment: Seems like DataTables works with  AJAX ; http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Answer (score 0):

I have since found [ingrid](http://reconstrukt.com/ingrid/) and will throw it out as a potential solution. It seems to do what I want though the look and feel seems quite heavy. I'll see how this answer is voted I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its from YUI, not JQuery, but I think it will do exactly what you need

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datatable/dt_dynamicdata.html

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery, several grids can modfiy html tables in-place.  Two I've used are flexigrid and jqgrid.

If you do this, you could for example, inject the html table using an ajax call (if necessary), then apply flexigrid() or jqgrid() on the resulting html table.